# Python - create a new column based on information within other columns

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, I am fairly new to python, so I'm probably making beginners mistakes. I'm sorry for that, but I cant seem to work this issue out on my own. I've tried different methods from other questions but still can't seem to find the right answer for my problem.

As part of my thesis, I am researching if a certain advertisements contribute to consumers' purchasing behavior. To do so, I want to check if consumers bought something within a timeframe of 4 days after opening an advertisement.

This is what i tried:

```
date1 = datetime.datetime(2017,1,16,hour=10,minute=5,second=55)
date2 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date3 = datetime.datetime(2017,2,13,hour=10,minute=10,second=55)
date4 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date5 = datetime.datetime(2017,3,1,hour=12,minute=19,second=9)
date6 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date7 = datetime.datetime(2017,3,17,hour=13,minute=43,second=32)
date8 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date9 = datetime.datetime(2017,3,22,hour=14,minute=12,second=19)
date10 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date11 = datetime.datetime(2017,4,7,hour=13,minute=32,second=42)
date12 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date13 = datetime.datetime(2017,4,14,hour=16,minute=3,second=53)
date14 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date15 = datetime.datetime(2017,4,24,hour=14,minute=57,second=16)
date16 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)
date17 = datetime.datetime(2017,5,2,hour=16,minute=47,second=14)
date18 = date1 + timedelta(days=4)

def online_purchases (df):
    if df['opened ad'] == 1:
        if df['date online purchase'] >= (date1,date2):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date3,date4):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date5,date6):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date7,date8):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date9,date10):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date11,date12):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date13,date1):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date15,date16):
            return 1
        elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date17,date18):
            return 1
    else: return 0
```

Then, I tried to apply the function in pandas as follows:
`df.apply (lambda df: online_purchases(df), axis=1)`

But then I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-311-3438fe67a3b4> in <module>
----> 1 df.apply (lambda df: online_purchases(df), axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\envs\master3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6012                          args=args,
   6013                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6014         return op.get_result()
   6015 
   6016     def applymap(self, func):

~\Anaconda3\envs\master3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\Anaconda3\envs\master3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

~\Anaconda3\envs\master3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-311-3438fe67a3b4> in <lambda>(df)
----> 1 df.apply (lambda df: online_purchases(df), axis=1)

<ipython-input-310-e871cdf87307> in online_purchases(df)
     21 def online_purchases (df):
     22     if df['ad geopend'] == 1:
---> 23         if df['date online purchase'] >= (date1,date2):
     24             return 1
     25         elif df['date online purchase'] >= (date3,date4):

pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__richcmp__()

TypeError: ("Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'tuple'", 'occurred at index 556')
```

Comment: `if df['date online purchase'] >= (date1,date2)`  Which one do you want, date1 or date 2?

Comment: I'm looking for a date that is later than date1 and earlier or the same as date2.

Comment: So `between` is what you want?

Comment: That would be: `if date1 < df['date online purchase'] <= date2`

Comment: That sounds good, try writing that way :)

Comment: It worked, thank you so much guys! :-)